# Cambiar el formato fecha

Tags: php, jquery, date

Buenas estoy intentando cambiar el formato de fecha que muestro en una tabla y no lo consigo. Con esto inserto los datos de un input date, en la bd tengo que el tipo de dato sea date.

```
try {
        $fecha_estreno = ($_POST['fecha_estreno']);
        $resultado = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO capitulos values ('$fecha_estreno')");
```

He probado varios metodos el último:

```
  $fechaNueva = date('Y/m/d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $fecha_estreno)));



$resultado = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO capitulos values ('$fechaNueva ')");
```

También he probado a meter formato al input directamente desde JQUERY.

```
  $("#fecha_estreno" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy" );



function insertarCapitulo(){
        var fecha_estreno=$("#fecha_estreno").val();
      console.log(fecha_estreno);
      $.ajax({
        url:"../acciones/insertarCapitulo.php",
        method: "POST",
        data:{fecha_estreno:fecha_estreno},
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(){
          alert ("Capitulo insertado correctamente");
          $("#nuevo").modal("hide");

        }
      });
    }
```

Me sigue mostrando la fecha así 1994-09-22, yo pienso que en el SELECT que uso para mostrarlo en la tabla no debe de ser, pienso que tiene que ser en el JQUERY.

**Los datos los inserto desde un modal con un input date. Estos campos luego muestro los muestro en otra pagina en el tbody. Trabajo con MSQL. El formato que deseo es dia-mes-año**

Comment: Hola, ¿dónde deseas *mostrar* el dato de fecha? En tu pregunta dices ***muestro en una tabla*** y luego dices que el campo donde insertas los registros es de tipo `date`. No aclaras cuál es el formato esperado. Y por último, si lo que deseas es que en tu base de datos se guarde la fecha con un formato específico, al menos podrías decir con qué motor de base de datos trabajas para poder darte una respuesta razonable. Saludos

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, ya añadí más info.

Comment: Yo lo utilizo así date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_estreno))

Comment: Nada, tiene que ser en el SELECT que uso para mostrar en la tabla, pero no consigo que lo muestre dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: probaste a darle formato a la fecha en la query?

Comment: Antes de ofrecerte una respuesta, me gustaría que me aclares una duda. En la base de datos se almacena la fecha de forma correcta? En bd se debe almacenar como YYYY-MM-DD. Esto es correcto y el único problema es para mostrarla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debmos tener en cuenta que para almacenar una fecha en mysql el formato debe ser `YYYY-MM-DD` o `YYYYMMDD` cualquier otro formato dará problemas.

Cuando queramos mostrarlo podemos manipular la fecha con la clase `DateTime` para mostrar la fecha con cualquier formato que deseemos.

Ejemplo para formatear una fecha:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2019-05-16');
echo $date->format('d-m-Y'); // 16-05-2019
?>
```

No indicas como te llega la fecha desde el formulario, pero dejas entrever que es un `<input type="date">` por defecto y según la especificación estos input envían la fecha en formato  `YYYY-MM-DD` que es el mismo que espera mysql. Debes a la hora de insertar un registro adaptarte a los formatos que mysql espera. Luego a la hora de mostrarlos podrás manipularlos como consideres oportuno.

También es posible ajustar el formato de fecha a mostrar con las funciones que mysql provee para tal fin ejemplo:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(campo_fecha, '%d-%m-%Y') fecha FROM tabla;
```

Documentación:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Con el SELECT que me pusiste si que muestra como quiero, ahora a la hora de ordenar por fecha no lo hace como quiero , así es como me lo muestra 
        02-03-1995
 03-11-1994
 04-05-1995
        05-01-1995
 06-04-1995
 06-10-1994
 09-02-1995
 09-03-1995
        10-11-1994
        11-05-1995 Yo quiero que lo muestre en orden 02-03-1993 , 04-03-1993...

Comment: @abc Pues ya dependen de por qué campo lo quieras ordenar. Simplemente aplicaselo al campo por el que quieras ordenar que quieras ordenar y también puedes añadirle `ASC` ascendente `DESC` descendente. Documentación https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Ya estoy probando, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Para que logres cambiar el formato de la fecha que estas trayendo de la base de datos, tienes que hacer lo siguiente

Almacena la consulta a tu base de datos, donde obtienes la fecha como `$consultaFecha` y pasa dicha variable a una instancia de la clase `new DateTime` que transforma lo que recibe en un objeto de tipo `datetime`

```
$fecha = new DateTime($consultaFecha);
```

Posterior para lograr cambiar el formato, has uso del método `format()` de este modo

```
echo $fecha->format("d-m-Y");
```

Ya con lo anterior logras modificar para mostrar el formato de la fecha directo desde el backend.

Es decir el formato con el que guardas la fecha seguirá siendo `YYYY-mm-dd` y solo para mostrarlo después con el formato `dd-mm-YYYY` hacemos lo anterior mostrado

Referencias

- [new DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.construct.php)

Comment: Lo tengo que meter en el SELECT o donde??   $resultado = $dbh->prepare("SELECT fecha_estreno FROM capitulos WHERE cod_temporada='T1' ORDER BY fecha_estreno ASC");
        $resultado->execute();
        while($registro = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $capitulos[]=$registro;

Comment: después de que llevas a cabo el `execute()` este es un ejemplo justo después del método mencionado yo hago esto `$fila = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$nuevaFecha = new DateTime($fila["inicio"]);

echo $nuevaFecha->format("d-m-Y");` @abc